# Making new zurb foundation column for each picture from looping pictures in rails view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am using zurb foundation to bootstrap my app. Currently I have something like this going on in the view

```
<h3>Friends</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-3 columns">
        <div class="friends">
          <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
            <tr>
            <td><%= friend.full_name %></td><br/>
            <td><%= image_tag(friend.image_url)%></td><br/>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its displaying multiple pictures. What I am trying to do is to create a "large-3 columns" for each picture and not be displaying all pictures inside one "large-3 columns". The pictures should end up side by side to each other.

I mostly focus on ruby on rails and less on the front end side. In my application.css I added this

```
.friends {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

to try to make the pictures happen side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for may be something like this.

```
<h3>Friends</h3>
<div class="row">
 <div class="large-12 columns">
   <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
     <div class="large-3 columns">
        <div class="friends">
         <tr>
            <td><%= friend.full_name %></td><br/>
            <td><%= image_tag(friend.image_url)%></td><br/>
          </tr>
        </div>
     </div>
   <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

You shouldn't need a nested row for this example. By placing the .large-3 column inside of your each loop, a new column will output for each friend object.

By default, Foundation columns will float left, so you shouldn't need to add anything for the columns to display as you are wanting them to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't forget that if your content's height is variable then you will need to clear your floats by adding .row every n-columns (4 in your case).